# How to handle exceptions for both ajax and page call

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, spring-boot, user-interface

We are working on spring boot UI application, since it is an UI application we are using ajax calls for some of the operations, as well as normal page calls(simply calling the  request mapping url).
Here the problem is, while making the ajax call and as well as normal page call if it caught by same type of  exception, how to handle that let say DataAccessException

```
    @ExceptionHandler(DataAccessException.class)
        public ModelAndView handleError(HttpServletRequest req, Exception ex) {
    logger.error("Request: " + req.getRequestURL() + " raised " + ex);

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.addObject("exception", ex);
    mav.addObject("url", req.getRequestURL());
    mav.setViewName("error");
    return mav;
  }
```

This data access exception should be served for both ajax request and normal page calls, but ajax response should not be a ModelAndView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following way i have tried, and it is worked

```
  @ExceptionHandler(DataAccessException.class)
        public Object handleError(HttpServletRequest req, DataAccessException ex) {
    logger.error("Request: " + req.getRequestURL() + " raised " + ex);
if("XMLHttpRequest".equals(request.getHeader("X-Requested-With")))
        {       
        ResponseEntity<String> dataExceptionRes=null;
dataExceptionRes=new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
return dataExceptionRes;
}
else{
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.addObject("exception", ex);
    mav.addObject("url", req.getRequestURL());
    mav.setViewName("error");
    return mav;
}
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to ensure that requests are distinguishable, e.g. all "normal page" requests end with `.html`, so their error response payload should also be an HTML page, while e.g. all other requests would send a JSON payload with the error response.

Of course, a more RESTful way would be content negotation, even for error responses, with perhaps a plain text default if no common format can be negotiated.